Denied boarding on RyanAir intra-Schengen despite valid German Residency travel documents
I am a non-EU passport holder with a German Aufenthaltstitel (aufenthaltserlaubnis) residency card, which expired, and thus I was issued a (stamped, official, but not laminated / plastic) Fiktionsbescheinigung, which has the "der Aufenthaltstitel als fortbestehend (§ 81 Abs. 4 AufenthG)" mark, allowing for travel out of and back into Germany. As one waits for a renewed residency, the Fiktionsbescheinigung is a very common travel document.
I travel throughout the EU with my passport, my residency card, and the Fiktionsbescheinigung constantly. I went from Malta to Greece on RyanAir just fine. Now, for the first time, on my return flight from Athens to Malta, I was denied boarding. The check-in counter agent simply said that the Fiktionsbescheinigung was not proof enough that I am legally allowed in the Schengen area. I showed boarding passes for previous RyanAir flights. No luck.
The flight was from Athens to Malta. I booked the next flight on Aegean, no questions asked.
Can I do something about the missed RyanAir flight and subsequent 400 euro Aegean flight, compensation wise? How do I prepare myself for future confrontations along these lines?

First: write a mail to Ryanair about the denied boarding: having written document is always good (and you may need to prove that you first trying to have an agreement with airline), then write to the national authority (I would try to German one), see contacts in https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

Did they check the documents at the check-in counter? Ryanair usually send people with non EU/EEA documents to a different counter for document verification.

They checked the documents at the check-in counter, yes. For intra-Schengen travel, I've never had a problem with a quick check at checkin (and, well, most of the time I don't even bother with the desk agents since I usually travel with no bags). Literally, if I hadn't had to checkin with bags, there would've been no issue. Asked for a supervisor, apparently there was nobody to review the case. By the time I had the airport police and an Aegean supervisor confirm that these documents were valid, the desk had closed.

Out of curiosity: do you have any confirmation that you've indeed talked to the agent and was denied boarding due to your documents, and not just e.g. never even tried to check in? I'd expect that would be the easiest way out for the airline.

The best way to prepare for future problems like this is to avoid them by avoiding crap airlines like ryanair. Almost all posts about problems with airlines are about one of crap airlines.

@jcaron they no longer require airside document verification for Schengen flights (source: flew with them last week)

@JonathanReez good thing they no longer send passengers to queue another time for this, but they still checked documents they didn’t need to in this instance (and got it wrong)…

First, as this was an internal Schengen flight, you should not need any documentation other than ID (and even that, not always) to board that flight. For some weird reason Ryanair go over the top on this and check anyone with a non EU/EEA passport even on internal Schengen flights, but this is actually not a legal requirement. It may even be illegal, though I don't think there's definitive word on that.
Next, the (very very long and complex — 120 pages!) list of residence permits which allow entry into and residence in the Schengen Area tells us:

GERMANY
(...)

All other documents issued to third-country nationals having equivalent value to a residence permit

(...)
Fiktionsbescheinigung
(Provisional residence document)
Only if the third box on page 3 is ticked – the residence permit continues to be valid. Entry is allowed only in connection with an expired residence permit, visa, a valid passport pursuant to Article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC, or a German permanent residence card pursuant to Article 20 of Directive 2004/38/EC.
If the first or second box is ticked, the “Fiktionsbescheinigung” does not entail the right of entry without a visa.

The third box is "der Aufenthaltstitel als fortbestehend (§ 81 Abs. 4 AufenthG)", which you tell us is ticked.
The agent was probably confused because the same document may or may not be valid depending on which box is ticked. I understand their plight given the very large number of documents and variations and the fact that a check in one box or another changes things, but they're just plain wrong, and should have supporting documentation (the above Annex 22 list) to make the correct decisions, and should refer to it when there is any doubt.
As you were incorrectly denied boarding, you are entitled to:

Compensation (250 euros in this case)
Reimbursement (refund) or rebooking at a later date.

It is a requirement that you first request this from the airline. It looks like this should happen from the "My Bookings" section of their website, but I don't know if the feature will be enabled in your case (as they certainly think you are not entitled to compensation or a refund). If you can't do it that way, you will have to use whatever contact form you can find to notify them. Alternatively, you can send them a letter (by registered mail).
If they refuse (which they will probably do), then you have to take it to a dispute resolution service and/or a national authority.
The alternative is to use the services of one of the many companies which will do all that for you, but will of course take a cut (usually 30%) of the proceeds.
Good luck!

Amazing answer, thank you! Will be sure to bring along some of these details and documentation to see if we can avoid this confusion in the future.

120 pages !!!!!!!!

@Fattie Welcome to Germany! ;)

brilliant!  indeed I am a Germany-o-phile and lived in Berlin a couple yrs.  My comment had the tone of voice "120 pages! so awesome! so German!"  :) :)

@arne It's not 120 pages just for Germany, thank goodness! It's for the whole Schengen Area. Exercise left for the reader: determine which country has the longest list.

As I commented once earlier, having had this with Ryanair on an intra-Schengen flight holding a USA passport (no visa issues whatever), I believe it's for a business model of profiting from fees and unused seats.


There is a god! After contacting the Greek Civil Aviation Authority it seems we got an answer.

WOW, something the Ryanair Immigration Dept. get right! Hallelujah! Congrats!
